# PayPal rest api always return INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR

Tags: python, paypal

I have a very simple Python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import paypalrestsdk

paypalrestsdk.configure({
  "mode": "live",
  "client_id": "...",
  "client_secret": "..." })

payment_history = paypalrestsdk.Payment.all({"count": 10})
print payment_history.payments
```

However, it always return INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR:

```
$ ./paypal.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./paypal.py", line 22, in <module>
    payment_history = paypalrestsdk.Payment.all({"count": 10})
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paypalrestsdk/resource.py", line 131, in all
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paypalrestsdk/api.py", line 219, in get
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paypalrestsdk/api.py", line 138, in request
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paypalrestsdk/api.py", line 166, in http_call
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paypalrestsdk/api.py", line 195, in handle_response
paypalrestsdk.exceptions.ServerError: Failed. Response status: 503. Response message: Service Unavailable. Error message: {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","information_link":"https://api.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"14a7e825c5d9d"}
```

Anyone know how to fix it? is there something simple I missed?

（In sandbox mode it return valid value "None".）

Comment: Internal service error means something broke inside PayPal. Ring 'em up and complain :). There is probably some aspect of your request that tripped up PayPal's internals, but you have no clues as to what (from PayPal, and you don't provide your full call details in the question either) so there's no decent way to diagnose. PayPal can trace based on that debug ID and get you some answer.

Comment: I've contacted PayPal technical support: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/ask_confirm/refno/150520-000453 but nobody answers. It sucks! Do they really care about customer issues?!

Comment: Your ticket was already responded.Login to your paypal.com/mts to follow-up, also if you are using REST API payouts we have an existing issue where it results in` INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR`, this is being fixed now.